# How is try catch evaluated in matlab?

Tags: matlab, try-catch

I wonder how a try-catch block is evaluated in matlab. In particular, is the try-catch block evaluated in runtime or "compile time"?

Also, is a try-catch block expensive?

If someone have a link to any documentation that would be much appreciated.

(Btw, I know that try-catch is not the best solution in most cases. Still I would like to know how it works, since I have used it in some code).

Answer (score 0):

> try and catch blocks allow you to override the default error behavior
>   for a set of program statements. If any statement in a try block
>   generates an error, program control goes immediately to the catch
>   block, which contains your error handling statements.

To learn more about try and catch in Matlab:[Try and Catch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html)

Try and catch block is always executed in run-time and is used to catch the errors that occur and has error-handling statements. So if your code generates some error and you want to handle it, use it. Using error-handling is good programming practice..

Comment: Try catch is not *always* evaluated in runtime. In java, the try block is compiled and in case of exceptions an exception object is created and searches the stack after a try. Also, if is possible to use if else instead of try catch in most cases. Personally I prefer that.